# Ingress Nginx - set static IP address in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-cloud-platform, ingress-controller, ingress-nginx

I use ingress nginx (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

This is how i build my project in GKE.

Step 1:
Install ingress controller (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke)

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.8.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Step 2: I use `skaffold dev` to run my k8s file.

Below is my ingress-srv file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    nginx-ingress.kubernets.io/user-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ''
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nix-api-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 3020
```

After that, I can get one external Ip address in GKE but when I delete the ingress controller and repeat step 1 (install the ingress controller again). I will get a new external Ip address.

How can I get a static Ip address even though i deleted the ingress controller?

Thank you

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/static-ip/), it is possible to use the same static-ip even though the Ingress controller is deleted and recreated.

Make sure your Ingress targets exactly one Ingress controller by specifying the **ingress.class** annotation in the yaml file.Since instances of the ingress NGINX controller actually run on nodes in a cluster, by default NGINX Ingresses will only get static IPs if the cloud provider supports static IP assignments to nodes.

To acquire a static IP for the ingress-nginx-controller, you can use the Service of **Type=LoadBalancer**.

Create a **Load balancer** Service with a name **ingress-nginx-lb** and wait for it to acquire an IP.

```
$ kubectl create -f static-ip-svc.yaml
service "ingress-nginx-lb" created

$ kubectl get svc ingress-nginx-lb 
It will show the details as below:
NAME        ingress-nginx-lb
CLUSTER-IP      10.0.138.113
EXTERNAL-IP     104.154.109.191
PORT(S)         80:31457/TCP,443:32240/TCP
AGE             15m
```

Once it is done, update the **Ingress controller** so it adopts the static IP of the Service by passing the **--publish-service** flag.

```
$ kubectl create -f ingress-nginx-controller.yaml 
deployment "ingress-nginx-controller" created
```

Every Ingress created with the **ingress.class** annotation set to **nginx** will get the IP which was allocated in the previous step

```
$ kubectl create -f ingress-nginx.yaml 
ingress "ingress-nginx" created

$ kubectl get ing ingress-nginx
It will show IP address for ingress-nginx as 104.154.109.191 (Same IP as Load balancer IP)
```

Additionally, You can specify a static IP address by using the **annotation** `kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name` on your Ingress resource as per the [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#static_ip_addressing).

To promote the allocated IP to static, you can update the Service manifest as follows:

```
$ kubectl patch svc ingress-nginx-lb -p '{"spec": {"loadBalancerIP": "104.154.109.191"}}' 
"ingress-nginx-lb" patched
```

Even if the **Ingress is deleted and re-created**, the **IP will be retained** by using the **Load balancer**. The same load balancer IP is shared amongst all Ingresses, because all requests are proxied through the same set of NGINX controllers.You can recreate the Service with **spec.loadBalancerIP set to 104.154.109.191**

Alternatively, you can also refer to the [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip) related to Static IP reservation.